# Ajax call request in CodeIgniter with CSRF enabled

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I am using an ajax call to save `value` of a radio button through hidden field in database using ajax call, used an alert to see if its working, and it is.

The URL I mentioned in the ajax call is redirecting it to a controller but I used an alert to see if its working, but its not working. Can't locate what's the issue.

Here is the code of ajax call in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#save').click(function(){
    var hint=$('#hidfield').val();
    alert('Oops, your response is '+hint);

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/save_answer',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "html",
        data:{hint:$hint, <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>: "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>"},
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
function save_answer()
{
    alert('You Can Do It !!');
    $data = array(
        'hint'=>$this->input->post('hint')
    );

    $this->base_model->save_answer($data);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
function save_answer($data)
{       
    $this->db->insert('questions',$data);
}
```

Please suggest some way out.

Comment: you have written js code in your controller ?

Comment: You can't have `alert('You Can Do It !!');` in your controller. You should also use `site_url` in your JS over `base_url`. Base URL will return the path to your CI install directory, not the CI index file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot used javascript "alert()" inside controller.
instead of  "alert('You Can Do It !!');" use  "die('You Can Do It !!');" to debug, and check in to your console.